# CMake/CPack Visual Studio .msi setup project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, windows-installer, cpack

Is it possible to use CMake and/or CPack to generate a Visual Studio .msi Windows Installer Setup project?
[Visual Studio create a new project wizard .msi Setup Project template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXxo8.png)